# why Ruby on Rails Scaffolding Fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scaffolding

i'm trying to make an scaffofold on rails V  5.2.1 but i have the following error [image: Error]

i already tried `gem pristine --all`
but not works thanks any help please

Comment: try to uninstall rvm completely then install it again

Answer (score 2):

Try bundle install..
The error which I could see in scaffold is Rails couldn't find the gem nokogiri .. make sure that your gemfile has the gem and then try running it

Comment: thanks that works, now i have another error
`<module:Scaffold>': undefined method `parse_config' for Puppet:Module (NoMethodError) mm i alredy add puppet gem to Gemfile

Comment: I'm not sure about this but I can help you if you share me the error screen?..Also check for the puppet gem version..